# stacknavigator react native set title of top menu

Tags: react-native, navigation, stack-navigator

i have a menu created like that :

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

   const stackNav = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
   screen: JourneeService,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
     headerTitle: <StackNavTitle title="Journée de Service " />,
      headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#0088CE',
     },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
       fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

    headerLeft: (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
      style={{width: '150%'}}>
      <Icon name="ios-menu" size={35} color="#fff" style={{padding: 10}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
}),
 }
```

with StackNavTitle :

```
class StackNavTitle extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

}

render() {
    return <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color:'#fff', fontSize:20}}> 
  {this.props.title}.   
  </Text>;
   }
  }
```

on code i retrieve a title by callback i want to set title dynamically how can i do that ?

thanks in advance for your responses

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a function to the header which accepts three parameters as per the docs and one of them contains the dynamic title. Here is an example I took from the docs and update with your header component

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

   const stackNav = createStackNavigator({
    Main: {
   screen: JourneeService,
    navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
     headerTitle: ({allowFontScaling, style, children})=> <StackNavTitle title={children.title} />,
      headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#0088CE',
     },
    headerTintColor: '#fff',
    headerTitleStyle: {
       fontWeight: 'bold',
    },

    headerLeft: (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
      style={{width: '150%'}}>
      <Icon name="ios-menu" size={35} color="#fff" style={{padding: 10}} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ),
}),
 }
```

You can find more info here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator#headertitle

Comment: how i set title in class after ?

Comment: Do you mean inside ```StackNavTitle ``` or from other screens?

Comment: From JourneeService component

Comment: I think you can do it like this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/headers/#setting-the-header-title